# Alpha in mtext in R

Tags: r

I would like to have the next label "log(L(Hα))"
I'm using

```
mtext(expression(paste("log(L(H",alpha)), side=1,outer=TRUE, cex = 1, line = 2.8)
```

However I obtain only log(L(Hα but I do need the last two brackets, how can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Please make your example reproducible http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Seems like you want `mtext(expression(log(L(H*alpha))), ...)` or `mtext(expression(log(L(H[alpha]))),...)`

Comment: That was so easy, thank you. It did work!